# Excel : count with multiple text criteria

Tags: excel

I have below excel data :-

```
     A              B             C
1  List A       List B            result
2  No           Critical            4
3  Yes          Critical    
4  Yes          Critical
```

In cell C2 I have used the `=COUNTIF(B2:B4,"Critical")+COUNTIF(A2:A4,"No")` formula. it returns result as 4. Because it found 3 occurrences of text "Critical" and single occurrence of text "NO". Hence the result is 4.

What I want is : it should give `result as 1`. I mean if row A has text "No" and row B has text "Critical" then only it count the result, it should not count any other combination. However using above formula it count irrespective looking into the combination. Is there formula other than `countif` perform the operation above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one for Excel 2007 and later:

```
=COUNTIFs(A2:A4,"No", B2:B4,"Critical")
```

for Excel 2003 you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4="No")*(B2:B4="Critical"))
```